Resources to learn about designing and analyzing cross-over trials from the lens of DAGs and potential outcomes
I am looking for good resources to learn about the proper design and analysis of randomized trials to compare treatment sequences. In other words, trials compare drug A before drug B to drug B before drug A.
I searched for resources but couldn't find any that discuss the topic from the potential (counterfactual) outcomes point of view.

The standard potential outcomes framework text is Imbens and Rubin's Causal Inference for Statistics, Social, and Biomedical Sciences: An Introduction. As I look at its table of contents, it spends an enormous amount of time on experiments. Does that not have what you're seeking?
